# Method to read local html file in react native webview (IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I am able to run my code on a simulator but failed on a physical device (ios). Do you guys have any idea what method should I replace the localhost?

Error Code: -1004 Could not connect to the server.

```
    let sources = (Platform.OS === "android" 
                   ? "file:///android_asset/"
                   : "http://localhost:8081/") + "Static.bundle/sample.html?data="
    
    <WebView source={{ uri: sources }} originWhitelist={["*"]}
```